# Исправьте проблему с кодом Python

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая выводит букву с заданным номером из каждой введённой строки. Это может использоваться, например, для конструирования аббревиатур или чтения акростихов. Если некоторые строки слишком короткие, и в них нет символа с заданным номером, то такие строки при выводе нужно просто пропускать.

**Формат ввода**

На первой строке вводится натуральное число — количество строк.
Далее следуют сами строки.
В конце вводится натуральное число — номер буквы (нумерация начинается с единицы).

**Формат вывода**

Буква с соответствующим номером из каждой строки; все буквы выводятся на одной и той же строке подряд.

```
spi = []
spi2 = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    stroki = input()
    spi.append(stroki)
cnt = int(input())
for elem in spi:
    if not elem[cnt - 1] in spi:
        continue
    else:
        spi2.append(elem[cnt - 1])
print("".join(spi2))
```

**Проблема в том, что не выдает результат(думаю потому что не идет добавление в список)**(см.скрин)
если поменять последнюю часть кода на:

```
for elem in spi:
    if elem[cnt - 1]:
        spi2.append(elem[cnt - 1])
    else:
        continue
```

то первый тест пройдет, а второй нет(по причине что вводится 10 позиция, а ее в строке допустим нет и выдает ошибку, именно поэтому я делаю сначала проверку на отсутствие определенной позиции в элементе)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что нужно исправить, чтобы программа работала? и стоит ли лучше использовать сначала проверку на **отсутствие** позиции в элементе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы что собственно проверяете в этой строке:

```
if not elem[cnt - 1] in spi:
    continue
```

Вы проверяете наличие **буквы** в **списке слов**. Это явно неправильное что-то.

Правильная проверка на то, что номер буквы не выходит за границу слова тут будет такая (хотя +/- могу ошибаться на одну позицию, надо проверять):

```
if cnt > len(elem):
    continue
```

Comment: Разве не наличие буквы на определенной позиции в списке?

Comment: Проверил, все работает верно!

Comment: @марат `in` проверяет наличие чего-то в чём-то. Так можно проверить наличие буквы в слове либо слова в списке слов.

Answer (score 2):

можно и немного покороче (чтобы ничего лишнего):

```
data = [input() for _ in range(int(input()))]

pos = int(input())

for text in data:
  if pos <= len(text):
    print(text[pos - 1], end='')
```

или даже так, если извращаться:

```
data, pos = [input() for _ in range(int(input()))], int(input())

[print(text[pos - 1], end='') for text in data if pos <= len(text)]
```

для вывода можно использовать и список, но без `join`:

```
data = [input() for _ in range(int(input()))]

pos = int(input())

print(*map(lambda text: text[pos - 1] if pos <= len(text) else '', data), sep='')
```

можно сделать тоже самое, но без тернарного оператора:

```
data = [input() for _ in range(int(input()))]

pos = int(input())

print(*map(lambda obj: obj[pos - 1], filter(lambda text: pos <= len(text), data)), sep='')
```